# Angular 5, i'm stuck with check an input eventKey

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to check an input that receive value from a keyboard and the value can't be more than 60. Everything work perfectly fine but when an 'ArrowUP' being press to 6-9 and keyboard still can be pressed. I don't know what i did wrong, please help!

Component

```
controlValue(event) {

let patt = /[0-9]/g;
let itTrue = patt.test(event.key);
console.log(this.startTime.minute)
if (itTrue || event.keyCode == 8 || (event.keyCode > 33 && event.keyCode < 48)) {
  if (event.code == 'ArrowUp') {
    this.startTime.minute++
    if (this.startTime.minute >= 60) {
      this.startTime.minute = 0;
    }
  } else if (event.code == 'ArrowDown') {
    this.startTime.minute--

    if (this.startTime.minute < 0) {
      this.startTime.minute = 59;
    }
  } else if (itTrue) {
    if ((this.startTime.minute + parseInt(event.key)) < 60) {

      console.log('return 1')
      return true
    }
    console.log('return 2')
    return false;
  } else {
    console.log('return 3')
    return true;
  }
} else {
  console.log('return 4')
  return false;
}
```

}

HTML

```
<input placeholder="MM" (keypress)="controlValue($event)" maxlength="2" [(ngModel)]="startTime.minute" class="form-control">
```

Comment: Can you please ellaborate more on your issue.?.

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya i created an input that only accept type number on the keyboard and value should not be more than 60. But when i'm pressing an arrowkeyUp to 6-9. It should not allow any number to typed in. but it did allow..

Comment: still not getting what is this line means ? 'when i'm pressing an arrowkeyUp to 6-9.'

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya Sorry, my English is bad. pressing an arrowkeyUp, to value = 6 or 7, 8 , 9

Comment: so the value should not be allow to type any further number because it will be more than 60+ but it did.

Comment: did u try the stackblitz

Comment: I did, still not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179378/discussion-between-suresh-kumar-ariya-and-max-kasem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use keydown event instead of keypress.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vkgr2p